# Системный вызов brk не работает

Tags: linux, ассемблер

Пишу на Android (aarch64). 4 Гб оперативки + 2 Гб swap. Захотел проверить, какой предел для расширения кучи (через brk). Пытаюсь увеличить аж на 10 гигов – и всё равно brk возвращает не код ошибки, а новый адрес.

Насколько мне известно, должно возвратиться 0, ежели память не может быть выделена. Во всяком случае, так работает библиотечная обёртка `brk()`. А если это не так, то возможно ли иным способом проверить, выделена ли память по факту? Как?

P.s. прошу про преимущества mmap не распыляться: хочу разобраться с вызовом brk, раз его ещё не выпилили из ядра.

Comment: Вообще-то не нужно им заниматься, программируя в ОС, поскольку так вы будете ломать функционирование malloc, которым пользуется все библиотечное окружение

Comment: Я понял, что вас озаботило. Читайте https://serverfault.com/a/142003 (а также вывод гугла по запросу `linux oom killer`  (кстати, **внимательно** почитать `man 2 brk` тоже не помешает))

Comment: brk не расширяет кучу... Для того чтобы проверить, выделена ли память по факту, к ней нужно обратиться, записать/прочитать.